# how can I center an image in ionic 2 app

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

hello I have some pages in an ionic 2 app, that have an  inside a .. like this

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <p>Some text here....</p>
  <p>Some other text here...</p>
  <ion-img width="180" height="180" src="assets/images/goal.jpg"></ion-img>  
  <p>bottom text here...</p>
</ion-content>
```

I need to see the image centered horizontally.. I have tested some css but without luck.. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 21):

You can use ionic [CSS utilities](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/) to align center by applying the attribute `text-center` to the parent element of the one you want to center horizontally.

Here is an example:

```
<ion-content text-center>
    <img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" width="128" />
</ion-content>
```

In your case I would wrap the `<img>` in a `<div>` so that it affects only the image and not the `<p>` elements.

Like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <p>Some text here....</p>
  <p>Some other text here...</p>
  <div text-center>
     <ion-img width="180" height="180" src="assets/images/goal.jpg"></ion-img>  
  </div>
  <p>bottom text here...</p>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: your answer save me

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content text-center>
    <p align="center"><ion-img src="assets/imgs/logo.png" width="128"></ion-img></p>
</ion-content>
```